# Exchange account authentication issue

Tags: macos, mail.app, exchange

[image]

Yesterday, this notification began appearing every time I open Mail.app  On hover, a continue button appears.    If I click it, it goes to Accounts pref pane, but there is no place to enter a password.    The password I've been using still works on the web-based version.    Items sent to my other account via web arrive in Mail.app, but items I send to my other account from Mail.app do not arrive, yet they do appear in the Sent folder on the web!

It's on a MacBook Pro.  I have never put that account on any other device.

The “easy” fix is to [delete and re-install the Exchange account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272172/apple-mail-outlook-exchange-account).  But the first time I tried that, Mail.app (not preferences) popped a modal dialog asking for the password.  Entered the same one, and the popup turned blank except for a busy cursor.  I waited a few minutes and clicked cancel.  Have tried to delete a few times since, and nothing at all happens (not even the pop-up).

I have neither [changed my password nor added two-factor auth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336730/unable-to-verify-account-name-or-password-on-outlook-com-exchange-server-brow) to exchange (if I did it ages ago and forgot—unlikely—it certainly wasn't yesterday).

**Reason, solution, prevention?**

Update: I noticed some other apps doing odd things, so I restored ~/Library with Time Machine from before the first malfunction was observed.  (Found some bugs in SIP doing so!)  Afterward, Mail.app showed connection errors on that account (it isn't before).  When I selected the account in SysPref, it asked me for password (unlike before) and when I put in the password, Mail was back to normal.  And the restore also fixed the other anomalies.

Comment: Version of macOS? Is Exchange server on-prem or 365?  Does your Exchange admin allow you to connect using Apple Mail?  FYI, latest Outlook for Mac w/365 is rather excellent.

Comment: Until Microsoft realizes that CalDAV/CardDAV do, in fact, exist, I don't think you can call any version of Outlook "excellent".

Comment: It’s an account I got in college, which the school allows alumni to keep.  And as I said, it had been working fine until yesterday.  I doubt the school would have decided to block all Mac users on a Saturday evening.  Even if they did, I doubt anything in the authentication protocols says “hey, I am a Mac, in case you want to block me”